# How do I create a --help option in a command-line program in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, command-line-interface

I'm pretty sure it's simple.  Is there a pre-defined header for create a help context in a command line program.

$ program --help

would provide a list of various help options.

Comment: If you're using a command line parser library, then it should have this option.  If you're parsing the command line yourself, then just detect the help option as you would any other flag/option, and print the help text.

Comment: Do you need it in C, or do you need it in C++?

Comment: You might want to read about [`getopt_long`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long).

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to do it in c++ is:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "--help")==0)
    {..print help here..}
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For C++, you have Boost.Program_options

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/program_options.html

But you'll have to bring the whole boost library (which can be tedious, the first time you do it).

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines...

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> cmdLineArgs(argv, argv+argc);

    for(auto& arg : cmdLineArgs)
    {
        if(arg == "--help" || arg == "-help")
        {
            std::cout << "Helpful stuff here\n";
        }
        else if(arg == "whatever")
        {
            std::cout << "whatever?!\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, there are libraries to handle cmd line arguments. But for simple stuff it's really not hard to do yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look to this library : [Getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html) which is part of the GNU C Library. It allows you to parse `-like` parameters efficiently.

Comment: As the OP is asking for `--help` it would be `getopt_long()`: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html#Getopt-Long-Option-Example

Answer (score 1):

[getopt_long](http://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2012/06/22/c-getopt_long-example-accessing-command-line-arguments/) is your friend. 
For one-character options, `getopt` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it multiple ways depending on how you want to go about it.

You could use strcmp() and just parse argv[1]:

```
if(strcmp(argv[1],"--help") == 0)
```

or you can use getopt if you are running linux:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html

Answer (score 0):

[Argp](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html) generates the output for the "--help" option automatically unless specified not to. It is part of the GNU library, and it makes it easier to keep your help option updated. Here's an example program and its output:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <argp.h>

const char *argp_program_version =
  "argp-ex3 1.0";
const char *argp_program_bug_address =
  "<bug-gnu-utils@gnu.org>";

/* Program documentation. */
static char doc[] =
  "Argp example #3 -- a program with options and arguments using argp";

/* A description of the arguments we accept. */
static char args_doc[] = "ARG1 ARG2";

/* The options we understand. */
static struct argp_option options[] = {
  {"verbose",  'v', 0,      0,  "Produce verbose output" },
  {"quiet",    'q', 0,      0,  "Don't produce any output" },
  {"silent",   's', 0,      OPTION_ALIAS },
  {"output",   'o', "FILE", 0,
   "Output to FILE instead of standard output" },
  { 0 }
};

/* Used by main to communicate with parse_opt. */
struct arguments
{
  char *args[2];                /* arg1 & arg2 */
  int silent, verbose;
  char *output_file;
};

/* Parse a single option. */
static error_t
parse_opt (int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state)
{
  /* Get the input argument from argp_parse, which we
     know is a pointer to our arguments structure. */
  struct arguments *arguments = state->input;

  switch (key)
    {
    case 'q': case 's':
      arguments->silent = 1;
      break;
    case 'v':
      arguments->verbose = 1;
      break;
    case 'o':
      arguments->output_file = arg;
      break;

    case ARGP_KEY_ARG:
      if (state->arg_num >= 2)
        /* Too many arguments. */
        argp_usage (state);

      arguments->args[state->arg_num] = arg;

      break;

    case ARGP_KEY_END:
      if (state->arg_num < 2)
        /* Not enough arguments. */
        argp_usage (state);
      break;

    default:
      return ARGP_ERR_UNKNOWN;
    }
  return 0;
}

/* Our argp parser. */
static struct argp argp = { options, parse_opt, args_doc, doc };

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct arguments arguments;

  /* Default values. */
  arguments.silent = 0;
  arguments.verbose = 0;
  arguments.output_file = "-";

  /* Parse our arguments; every option seen by parse_opt will
     be reflected in arguments. */
  argp_parse (&argp, argc, argv, 0, 0, &arguments);

  printf ("ARG1 = %s\nARG2 = %s\nOUTPUT_FILE = %s\n"
          "VERBOSE = %s\nSILENT = %s\n",
          arguments.args[0], arguments.args[1],
          arguments.output_file,
          arguments.verbose ? "yes" : "no",
          arguments.silent ? "yes" : "no");

  exit (0);
}
```

```
./argp-example --help
Usage: argp-example [OPTION...] ARG1 ARG2
Argp example #3 -- a program with options and arguments using argp

  -o, --output=FILE          Output to FILE instead of standard output
  -q, -s, --quiet, --silent  Don't produce any output
  -v, --verbose              Produce verbose output
  -?, --help                 Give this help list
      --usage                Give a short usage message
  -V, --version              Print program version

Mandatory or optional arguments to long options are also mandatory or optional
for any corresponding short options.

Report bugs to <bug-gnu-utils@gnu.org>.
```